# Filtar personas seleccionando la opción desde un select, con php, mysql y ajax, javascript

Tags: javascript, php, mysql, ajax

alguien que me pueda ayudar con eso, me gustaría que al seleccionar una opción en el select por ejemplo: Brasil, me muestre todas las personas que viajo a Brasil, con php puedo hacerlo pero me muestra el resultado en otra pagina y me gustaría mostrar en la misma pagina.

Código php que trae en el selec las personal:

```
<div class="container">
<div class="page-header">
<h3>
<select id="personal">
<option value="" selected="selected">Selecionar Viaje</option>
<?php
$sql = "SELECT * FROM viajes";
$resultset = mysqli_query($conn, $sql) or die("database error:". mysqli_error($conn));
while( $rows = mysqli_fetch_assoc($resultset) ) { 
?>
<option value="<?php echo $rows["viaje_id"]; ?>"><?php echo $rows["motivo"]; ?></option>
<?php } ?>
</select>
</h3>   
</div>  
<br>
<div id="display">
<div class="row" id="heading" style="display:none;">
<br><h5>Resultados de la Base de Datos.</h5><br>           
<table class="table">
<thead class="thead-dark">
<tr>
<th scope="col">#</th>
<th scope="col">Nombre Empleado</th>
<th scope="col">Edad</th>
<th scope="col">Salario</th>
<th scope="col">Viajes</th>
</tr>
</thead>
<tbody>
<tr>
<th scope="row">1</th>
<!--ACA SE CARGAN LOS DATOS DEL JS, FUNCIONA PERO SOLO ME TRAE UNO-->
<td><div class="col-sm-3" id="emp_nombre"></div></td>
<td><div class="col-sm-3" id="emp_edad"></div></td>
<td><div class="col-sm-3" id="emp_salario"></div></td>
<td><div class="col-sm-3" id="emp_viajes"></div></td>
</tr>
</tbody>
</table>   
</div>
<br>        
<div class="row" id="no_records">
<div class="col-sm-10">Por favor, seleccione el nombre del empleado para ver los detalles</div></div>
</div>      
</div>
```

Codigo PHP que trae las personas getPersonal.php:

```
<?php
include_once("conexion.php");
if($_REQUEST['empid']) {
    
    $sql = "SELECT viajes.viaje_id, viajes.motivo, personal.id, personal.nombre_personal, personal.salario_personal, personal.edad_personal, personal.id_viaje FROM viajes LEFT JOIN personal ON personal.id_viaje = viajes.viaje_id WHERE viaje_id='".$_REQUEST['empid']."'";
        
    $resultset = mysqli_query($conn, $sql) or die("database error:". mysqli_error($conn));
    
    $data = array();
    while( $rows = mysqli_fetch_assoc($resultset) ) {
        $data = $rows;
    }
    echo json_encode($data);
} else {
    echo 0; 
}
?>
```

Código JS que trae los resultados.

```
$(document).ready(function(){  
    // code to get all records from table via select box
    $("#personal").change(function() {    
        var id = $(this).find(":selected").val();
        var dataString = 'empid='+ id;    
        $.ajax({
            url: 'getPersonal.php',
            dataType: "json",
            data: dataString,  
            cache: false,
            success: function(employeeData) {
               if(employeeData) {
                    
                    $("#heading").show();         
                    $("#no_records").hide();
//eso me funciona pero trae una sola persona
//la idea es traer todas las personas con el mismo motivo de viaje                  
                    $("#emp_nombre").text(employeeData.nombre_personal);
                    $("#emp_edad").text(employeeData.edad_personal);
                    $("#emp_salario").text(employeeData.salario_personal);
                   $("#emp_viajes").text(employeeData.motivo);
                    $("#records").show();        
                } else {
                    $("#heading").hide();
                    $("#records").hide();
                    $("#no_records").show();
                }       
            } 
        });
    }) 
});
```

Tabla personas:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Tabla viajes:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

me pidieron que ponga todo el código, así que ahí esta todo el código, dígase que ese código lo baje de internet (como me recomendaron) y lo modifico para que ande con mi proyecto, no se mucho de AJAX así que no se donde cambiar para poder traer todos los viajes de una persona determinada.
Edward Romero me paso un código pero igual no me funciona.

Answer (score 0):

Asumiendo que no hay otros problemas. En tu código has cometido unos pequeños errores:

1. En el `while` debes ir metiendo en `$data` un nuevo array por cada fila, para ello debes usar  `[]`
2. Al recibir la respuesta en Ajax, dado que recibirás varias filas, debes usar un bucle para recuperar esas filas. Debo decir que en ese punto de tu Ajax no has entendido bien el asunto, pues refieres a los elementos por su id cuando lo que deberías es construir `N` filas, según la cantidad de filas que recibas del servidor. No me meteré con eso, mostraré en consola los datos simplemente, luego organiza tú el HTML como mejor te convenga. He puesto un laaargo comentario en ese punto tratando de explicarte. Si no lo has entendido, pregunta en comentario. Sigues una lógica confusa ahí y hay cosas que no concuerdan con lo que parece que quieres.
3. Cuando esperes una respuesta en JSON, no salgas por Peteneras en algunos puntos de tu código. Lo digo porque cuando tu conexión falla resuelves con un `die()` ... ¡PERO si ese `die()` va a romper tu JSON resultando en un error cuando quieras leer la respuesta en el cliente! Incorpora todas las ramas del código en una respuesta en forma de array, y responde con ese array. Y, en otros casos resuelves con `0`, que también va a romper el JSON. Falta madurez en tu código y falta uniformidad. Si el cliente espera un JSON, debes responder un JSON aunque el mundo se acabe.

Vamos a aplicar lo dicho:

#### `getPersonal.php`

```
<?php
    $data=array();
    $id=$_REQUEST['empid'] ?? NULL;
    if($id) {
        include_once("conexion.php");
        if ($conn) {    
            $sql = "SELECT viajes.viaje_id, viajes.motivo, personal.id, personal.nombre_personal, personal.salario_personal, personal.edad_personal, personal.id_viaje FROM viajes LEFT JOIN personal ON personal.id_viaje = viajes.viaje_id WHERE viaje_id='$id'";        
            if( $resultset = mysqli_query($conn, $sql) ) {
                $allRows=array();
                while( $rows = mysqli_fetch_assoc($resultset) ) {
                    $allRows[] = $rows;
                }
                if ($allRows) {
                    $data['rows']=$allRows;
                } else {
                    $data['error']='0 filas encontradas';
                }
            } else {
                $data['error']='Error en la consulta SQL';
            }
        } else {
            $data['error']='No hay conexión';
        }
    } else {
        $data['error']='No se postearon datos';
    }
    echo json_encode($data);
?>
```

Si observas, hemos aplicado una lógica en el código anterior según la cual, cualquier error que haya, la respuesta tendrá una clave `error`, con una descripción del error ocurrido. Se llama coherencia. Cuando trabajas en contextos como estos debes verificarlo todo, para informar al cliente de lo que haya ocurrido. Imagina un contexto cualquiera donde un cliente te pregunte algunas cosas y no le des ninguna respuesta. Si trasladamos eso a tu código original, el mismo era **mudo** en varios puntos. Un programa así es deficiente, no será nunca un programa maduro.

Veamos ahora cómo manejar esta respuesta en el cliente:

#### Javascript

```
$(document).ready(function(){  
    // code to get all records from table via select box
    $("#personal").change(function() {    
        var id = $(this).find(":selected").val();
        var dataString = 'empid='+ id;    
        $.ajax({
            url: 'getPersonal.php',
            dataType: "json",
            data: dataString,  
            cache: false,
            success: function(employeeData) {
               if(employeeData.error) {
                    alert(employeeData.error);
               } else {
                    /*
                        En PHP pusimos que cuando haya datos,
                        los mismos vendrían bajo una clave 'rows'
                        y pueden ser varias filas,
                        por tanto, hace falta un bucle para leerlos
                        Incorpora esto según tu HTML
                        pues no entiendo la lógica confusa 
                        que estás siguiendo en este punto
                        refiriendo por ejemplos los elementos
                        por su id, lo cual no tiene sentido
                        porque ni siquiera sabes cuántos elementos
                        vas a recibir.
                    */
                    $.each(employeeData.rows, function (i, obj) {
                        console.log(obj.nombre_personal);
                        console.log(obj.edad_personal);
                        //etc ...
                    });        
               }                                 
            } 
        });
    }) 
});
```

Comment: Muchas gracias por su extensa explicación, se nota que es un erudito de la informática, al cambio yo, soy solo un principiante, y como comente en mi pregunta, no se mucho de AJAX así que el problema es el mismo, que poner adentro del else? necesito que me traiga todos las personas que eligieron el mismo motivo de viaje. Gracias

Comment: @SidneyAlan-DesignerProgra me parece que la respuesta dada resolvería tu problema. ¿Has intentado con este código? ¿Qué respuesta obtienes?

Comment: Hola, el problema es que no se que poner adentro del else en el javascript, donde estan los comentarios

Comment: @SidneyAlan-DesignerProgra pues ahí pon lo que necesites. Supongamos que necesitas filas (tr), entonces puedes construir una fila por cada registro obtenido y las celdas (td) serían cada una de las propiedades de `obj`. Si aclaras lo que necesitas ahí puedo editar la respuesta para mostrar un ejemplo.